# how to change address based on a value in another cell in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

```
I need to pull data from the source spreadsheet  $Units_Weekly, from a changing column.
The start is column O  ----> $Units_Weekly.$O2
Column name changes in A50. The next column name will be P,
it's based on a condition. 

How it is possible to link A50 and $Units_Weekly.$O2, instead of O? 
I mean to insert content of A50 into the formula above, replacing O
with contents of A50?
I have tried to use direct substitution but that does not work. 
This gives error ====>  $Units_Weekly.$&"A50&"2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following what you wrote, but I wonder if the problem here is syntax errors, not pulling from a different sheet?

`$` indicates an absolute reference. In your example, you're telling Calc that the sheet name `Units_Weekly` is absolute (fixed) rather than relative (changeable).

`&` is the concatenation symbol.

When quote marks `" "` surround something, it means you want what's between them to be treated as text. So the way you wrote it, Calc thinks `A50&` is text. You probably meant it to be a cell reference (`A50`) followed by a concatenation symbol (`&`).

Say, for instance, the contents of `Units_Weekly.A50` is the word "magnolia". This formula:
`=$Units_Weekly.$A50&"2"` would produce the output `magnolia2`. It tells Calc to concatenate the contents of cell A50 on sheet Units_Weekly with the number `2` treated as text.

Tip: When you're having trouble with a formula, simplify it as much as possible until you get something that works, then gradually add in complexity. Example:

First step: put the letter 'a' in cell A1, the letter 'b' in A2, and then in A3 write the simplest possible concatenation formula: `=A1&A2`. This should give you the result `ab` in cell A3.

Second step: change your formula to make the column and/or row references absolute, for instance `=$A1&$A2` Make sure your result is still `ab`. That'll let you know you have the dollar signs and ampersands in the right places.

Then substitute external sheet references, the correct cells instead of A1 and A2, and so forth. One step at a time.